# Reading multiple tables from one tsv file to an R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I want to read the data from github in R. Here is my code.

```
library(tidyverse)
cluster_tables <- read_tsv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hodcroftlab/covariants/master/cluster_tables/all_tables.tsv", skip_empty_rows = T)
```

It only reads first column and does not show the rest of the columns. How can I get this dataset as one dataframe in R? Also, is there a way to create a column with the hashtaged table names on this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the data with `skip = 4`

```
cluster_tables <- readr::read_tsv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hodcroftlab/covariants/master/cluster_tables/all_tables.tsv", skip = 4, skip_empty_rows = TRUE)
head(cluster_tables)

#   X1             first_seq  num_seqs last_seq  
#  <chr>          <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     
#1 Netherlands    2020-06-20 1615     2021-01-21
#2 Spain          2020-06-20 2003     2021-01-12
#3 United Kingdom 2020-07-07 69421    2021-01-23
#4 Belgium        2020-07-17 384      2021-01-20
#5 Switzerland    2020-07-22 1706     2021-01-19
#6 Ireland        2020-07-23 603      2021-01-22
```

---

Since there are multiple tables on the page to read them automatically in one dataframe we can do some manipulation.

- Read the data with `readLines`
- Remove all the empty lines
- split the dataset into a new list whenever `'##'` is encountered.
- For every list separate the first value which is the name of the table and add it as a new column.
- Combine list of dataframes in one big dataframe (`result`).

```
tmp <- readLines('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hodcroftlab/covariants/master/cluster_tables/all_tables.tsv')
tmp <- tmp[tmp != '']

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(tmp, cumsum(grepl('##', tmp))), function(x) {
  name <- sub('##\\s+', '', x[1])
  x <- x[-1]
  transform(read.csv(text = paste0(x, collapse = '\n'), sep = '\t'), name = name)
})) -> result

head(result)
#                 X  first_seq num_seqs   last_seq    name
#1.1    Netherlands 2020-06-20     1615 2021-01-21 20A.EU1
#1.2          Spain 2020-06-20     2003 2021-01-12 20A.EU1
#1.3 United Kingdom 2020-07-07    69421 2021-01-23 20A.EU1
#1.4        Belgium 2020-07-17      384 2021-01-20 20A.EU1
#1.5    Switzerland 2020-07-22     1706 2021-01-19 20A.EU1
#1.6        Ireland 2020-07-23      603 2021-01-22 20A.EU1
```

Comment: Thanks! These are multiple dataframes on one page. Is there a way to create a column with those hashtaged table names on this page?

Comment: I did not notice that. You should have added information about names in the main question. I have updated the answer to show how to read them in one dataframe with the name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, updated the question. Thanks for the updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah) from the above answer, I tried with tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)    

cluster_tables <- readLines('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hodcroftlab/covariants/master/cluster_tables/all_tables.tsv')

cluster_tables %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate(value, into = c("countries", "first_seq", "num_seqs", "last_seq"), sep = "\t") %>% 
  filter(countries != "") %>% 
  mutate(variants = if_else(str_detect(countries, "## "), countries, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(variants, .direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(first_seq))

head(cluster_tables)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  countries      first_seq  num_seqs last_seq   variants  
  <chr>          <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     
1 Netherlands    2020-06-20 1615     2021-01-21 ## 20A.EU1
2 Spain          2020-06-20 2003     2021-01-12 ## 20A.EU1
3 United Kingdom 2020-07-07 69421    2021-01-23 ## 20A.EU1
4 Belgium        2020-07-17 384      2021-01-20 ## 20A.EU1
5 Switzerland    2020-07-22 1706     2021-01-19 ## 20A.EU1
6 Ireland        2020-07-23 603      2021-01-22 ## 20A.EU1
```